python requests different from curl request
Hi I want to get some informations from one website. This is the curl command:
curl 'https://www.kleinanzeigen.de/s-iphone-13/k0' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7' \
  -H 'accept-language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,ru-DE;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.5' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'cookie: _clck=or3005%7C2%7Cfly%7C0%7C1602; CSRF-TOKEN=14dc299d-30f2-4d98-9ff4-c4fbe8f3e569; ak_bmsc=C1C8A8F7FF391E9820102E8CA4EBB694~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQhmZWuGSaVnmPAQAA1pftnBc7BqlNSSkxUM+mIQNkQI3yuVFydinhQtGa20uPsi5nOxA4EWd/piq70XNXFMfMUS/ryvVLMfNDLkEIJ/voevw9rWS4yLRqSn8kGbnehmg3KwRO0VmTEmjPk7QKEZU6yUU6zGiCu5f6lFCyt+7FT+FmtaM2Hje0ugHMveYB+nqJgasPgrwgJggxSChqa/QpR4M6f9Sckw92ci6oQ2O3MzksBAlzMYeVGRXSDv7eNwk10ysBrBOOECdbYmieHjyHk8Toqub9nL2Rm7vdvtmx2nPUt+SiA4ZjkksVDw9I8Gc5YVOC2crta/zObr+6vZp5hR1B7WeJ7slQCtAOsbBYFz7tnqY7ex8fzEQKezCKvpBIw8LnT/GrwN9MnPYgAcp8mhTkRehrFgHHN1O0TmgSYduWXHusOW8E1SqPYGQeCuNC943d6jJ83MVACpX+AzFd4gJdgrPgTNstbfVsTq0xRp/mj4wnW5lviA==; ekConsentBucketTcf2=full2-exp; ekConsentTcf2={%22customVersion%22:6%2C%22encodedConsentString%22:%22CP-9ugAP-9ugAE1ACADEAzEgAP_gAAAAAAYgJepV5D7dbWFFcX53aPt0OY0X19DzIsQhBhSBAyAFgBOQ8JQA02EyNASgBiACEAAAoxZBAAFEHABEAQCAQAAEAADsIgQEgAAIIABEgBEQAAJYAAoKAAAgEAAIgAIFEgAAmBjQKdLmXUiAhIAACgAQACABAICAAgMAAAAIAAIAAAAAAgAAgABgIAIAAAAAARAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAACi0AGAAIJelIAMAAQS9JQAYAAgl6QgAwABBL0dABgACCXoyADAAEEvRUAGAAIJeiIAMAAQS9DQAYAAgl6EgAwABBL0A.YAAAAAAAA60A%22%2C%22googleConsentGiven%22:true%2C%22consentInterpretation%22:{%22googleAdvertisingFeaturesAllowed%22:true%2C%22googleAnalyticsAllowed%22:true%2C%22infonlineAllowed%22:true%2C%22theAdexAllowed%22:true%2C%22criteoAllowed%22:true%2C%22facebookAllowed%22:true%2C%22amazonAdvertisingAllowed%22:true%2C%22rtbHouseAllowed%22:true%2C%22linkedInAllowed%22:true%2C%22theTradeDeskAllowed%22:true%2C%22microsoftAdvertisingAllowed%22:true%2C%22pianoAllowed%22:true%2C%22renaultAllowed%22:false}}; iom_consent=0107ff0000&1716324769286; _gid=GA1.2.1532272070.1716324769; __rtbh.uid=%7B%22eventType%22%3A%22uid%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22unknown%22%7D; clientId=496654825.1716324769; _gat=1; FPID=FPID2.2.AOuBPGhHzWT6LnAkpY5kTJhKrpSS%2FkCqyy4lC0XgstU%3D.1716324769; FPLC=q%2BEjZGxjkPyzi60Jabi2fnha46CbqeBJ6r5U2WbreeneTYQSQm2wogu4TCxyjhFwIpCvNTT5dL%2FIMuVk77ixOiL%2Btpwkr%2BhfOXvIFfaYo8901edWtL0mN0jGi%2FQbew%3D%3D; FPAU=1.2.1242298381.1716324771; FPGSID=1.1716324770.1716324770.G-6V6MWRHVN8.TCed7UzLYaViqx_51MOpqg; up=%7B%22ln%22%3A%22294028564%22%2C%22lln%22%3A%229813e7ea-faff-435e-a600-244146dd8da9%22%2C%22llstv%22%3A%22BLN-25381-ka-offboarding%3DB%7CBLN-23401_buyNow_in_chat%3DB%7CBLN-18532_highlight%3DA%7CBLN-23248_BuyNow_SB%3DB%7CBLN-22726_buyer_banner%3DB%7Cignite_web_better_session%3DC%7CEBAYKAD-3536_floor_ai%3DA%7Cignite_improve_session%3DC%7CBLN-24684-enc-brndg-data%3DA%7Cliberty_group%3DY%7CFLPRO-130-churn-reason%3DB%7CEKMO-100_reorder_postad%3DB%7CKLUE-274-financing%3DB%7Clws-aws-traffic%3DB%7CBLN-25450_Initial_message%3DB%7CBLN-24652_category_alert%3DB%7CBLN-21783_testingtime%3DB%7Caudex-awr-update%3DA%7CEBAYKAD-2252_group-assign%3DH%7CBLN-25216-new-user-badges%3DB%7CBLN-25556_INIT_MSG_V2%3DB%7CDESKTOP-promo-switch%3DA%7Caudex-libertyjs-reporting%3DA%7CPLC-189_plc-migration%3DB%7Caudex-libertyjs-update%3DA%7Cperformance-test-desktop%3DC%7CBIPHONE-9700_buy_now%3DB%7CEKMO-243_MyAdsC2b_ABC%3DA%7Cprebid-update%3DA%7CEKTNM-4424_DSA_AD_FLAG%3DA%7Cpubads-behind-consent%3DA%7CPLC-104_plc-login%3DB%7Cdesktop_payment_badge_SRP%3DR%22%2C%22ls%22%3A%22k%3Diphone%252013%22%7D; uh=%7B%22sh%22%3A%22k%3Diphone%252013%22%7D; bm_sv=0E46F6D4C2D15DDF4037D3219522F169~YAAQjGZWuLYmhJGPAQAAc7HtnBfptI0O/cZh+z71bjX7FWoEWfWi+7rSmJtAdtnHr2Yy6Sml0PivsexsxpEKRqSMQ6ykXGA2uoSw845qdTHuHFptR+QNvMHbvH/VH/cLCl5ACpcudk630IFOv5PevfMyfExV481WLWdi/qiNeZTnGPaMNkfNGtb6nRhJan8bo9pPBMP4ZvblfI33UGrSX3mmVIEuQ2CZ9w2o6QF97BCNHkRLzeHAyzVnysmuxchKgTS4GHCq~1; bm_sz=DC20044AB93A95DA69EEDF3CBC61933F~YAAQjGZWuLcmhJGPAQAAc7HtnBfghyhORTugDA+HeFjnh5DSij+T1QpBc1T3YOBc7JF2Kd/LUNEwSqqPtyRQMQqA6S5UoqG2w3rLfYD4LfF3p4Oe35m8blAYcoozf4uBqfBuD4kPWSAEdCCW4Qz3yPBOFwLGDO3Imik7kxYRH+0PpEGheEoo6JQSXKpdHrGRhLXOJecz1EKW/uRKZf2n35KDL7Q5uNdu4ZMkwKG4Tsv2b1lNYr5AsR+OyvPuTnHyGbyIo3IsqmoeL4ZDBvgdGlrbhcAyJdm6D8HFNyaNgCIPLyiH/nbL1Md2mVu99LlQHI/atUHs2Xls/fNrHeiEM14d1gRlmS+0t5wt2eB+C3k4KUgjrpSta8jR7hvBMHq+JWrZ71tUnLjVXgozyprHuWzgQYHSN8DQE9lVEBtuqbkyO0eQZmUPJoUBf/p7raJ7rGiX+R6P~3225913~3749176; _pbjs_userid_consent_data=1948453571612999; _sharedid=2cc48544-17d6-40f0-8055-433f3bd0eebb; ttd_TDID=5af2038d-4201-4381-a705-008be357e42b; _abck=0BE7DECF6A441CAED9FAE60DD4A2D439~-1~YAAQjGZWuGYnhJGPAQAAF7ntnAvIJaPDK0JcFilje/7MpZxzpI0e91nvMkptlAnNzcvbc/7RsC1cJb9t+U/5WcPd8vR5hPtB4B5DzzMkYqetbfONwbgM9rxJ7WzQZDmNXvHso6HgE1CoHrazlFHCdapmnPYQZf9rKTSLi3bpmBLXajRz9jguHHl/OSeKz60PNLlcnQKxgUbDiS2dOz9K/fdl5pYP8fD54/2/h6P9mGBtoAeUAxPNRUZNuqgo3KhfSpryre97I0qQjtZIffvnvrTTh+VGLk+XXGxxWA3+KQZ7fk89MhFNR6X6iPIln2KisoLu/M7FUsmhBUHuGW4GYxSuzePypKxJLosRLHD2VngeRjrSbP5dEuFI0ib3ZbVGoOm0EdrBwwg4gtTbfH82~-1~-1~-1; ioam2018=001004bb35748f346664cf549:1742244769311:1716324769311:.kleinanzeigen.de:3:ebaykanz:ebayK-2:noevent:1716324775481:xwyv7z; __gsas=ID=06678aa415f2bae1:T=1716324775:RT=1716324775:S=ALNI_MY8M9AWvnu9c04kmWUotsmzbZE9Kw; _uetsid=24053ee0178711ef995c73a37e750a44; _uetvid=2815b710edc911edb77b397abfb0ec6b; _ga=GA1.1.496654825.1716324769; __gads=ID=913a6a8a4ed5f68f:T=1716324775:RT=1716324775:S=ALNI_MbcqPiXeD1up-CfoDLjbZWHR3i2qQ; __gpi=UID=00000e283afa9424:T=1716324775:RT=1716324775:S=ALNI_MaKh8LN1b8hyjtkjGF1q_PBkaguBQ; __eoi=ID=30ca85bff1e0487a:T=1716324775:RT=1716324775:S=AA-AfjZA4xIy4PLoxMR9l_uqa7AS; _ga_123456=GS1.1.1716324776.1.0.1716324776.0.0.1971217686; _clsk=kf2mvr%7C1716324777066%7C2%7C0%7Cv.clarity.ms%2Fcollect; _ga_6V6MWRHVN8=GS1.1.1716324769.1.1.1716324777.0.0.804489043; axd=4362638687387987014; tis=' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'priority: u=0, i' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="125", "Chromium";v="125", "Not.A/Brand";v="24"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

When I use this request it works totaly fine and the response is correct. However I want to use python for this (I used curlconverter.com) and this is the python code:
import requests

cookies = {
    '_clck': 'or3005%7C2%7Cfly%7C0%7C1602',
    'CSRF-TOKEN': '14dc299d-30f2-4d98-9ff4-c4fbe8f3e569',
    'ak_bmsc': 'C1C8A8F7FF391E9820102E8CA4EBB694~000000000000000000000000000000~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',
    'ekConsentBucketTcf2': 'full2-exp',
    'ekConsentTcf2': '{%22customVersion%22:6%2C%22encodedConsentString%22:%22CP-9ugAP-9ugAE1ACADEAzEgAP_gAAAAAAYgJepV5D7dbWFFcX53aPt0OY0X19DzIsQhBhSBAyAFgBOQ8JQA02EyNASgBiACEAAAoxZBAAFEHABEAQCAQAAEAADsIgQEgAAIIABEgBEQAAJYAAoKAAAgEAAIgAIFEgAAmBjQKdLmXUiAhIAACgAQACABAICAAgMAAAAIAAIAAAAAAgAAgABgIAIAAAAAARAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAACi0AGAAIJelIAMAAQS9JQAYAAgl6QgAwABBL0dABgACCXoyADAAEEvRUAGAAIJeiIAMAAQS9DQAYAAgl6EgAwABBL0A.YAAAAAAAA60A%22%2C%22googleConsentGiven%22:true%2C%22consentInterpretation%22:{%22googleAdvertisingFeaturesAllowed%22:true%2C%22googleAnalyticsAllowed%22:true%2C%22infonlineAllowed%22:true%2C%22theAdexAllowed%22:true%2C%22criteoAllowed%22:true%2C%22facebookAllowed%22:true%2C%22amazonAdvertisingAllowed%22:true%2C%22rtbHouseAllowed%22:true%2C%22linkedInAllowed%22:true%2C%22theTradeDeskAllowed%22:true%2C%22microsoftAdvertisingAllowed%22:true%2C%22pianoAllowed%22:true%2C%22renaultAllowed%22:false}}',
    'iom_consent': '0107ff0000&1716324769286',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.1532272070.1716324769',
    '__rtbh.uid': '%7B%22eventType%22%3A%22uid%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22unknown%22%7D',
    'clientId': '496654825.1716324769',
    '_gat': '1',
    'FPID': 'FPID2.2.AOuBPGhHzWT6LnAkpY5kTJhKrpSS%2FkCqyy4lC0XgstU%3D.1716324769',
    'FPLC': 'q%2BEjZGxjkPyzi60Jabi2fnha46CbqeBJ6r5U2WbreeneTYQSQm2wogu4TCxyjhFwIpCvNTT5dL%2FIMuVk77ixOiL%2Btpwkr%2BhfOXvIFfaYo8901edWtL0mN0jGi%2FQbew%3D%3D',
    'FPAU': '1.2.1242298381.1716324771',
    'FPGSID': '1.1716324770.1716324770.G-6V6MWRHVN8.TCed7UzLYaViqx_51MOpqg',
    'up': '%7B%22ln%22%3A%22294028564%22%2C%22lln%22%3A%229813e7ea-faff-435e-a600-244146dd8da9%22%2C%22llstv%22%3A%22BLN-25381-ka-offboarding%3DB%7CBLN-23401_buyNow_in_chat%3DB%7CBLN-18532_highlight%3DA%7CBLN-23248_BuyNow_SB%3DB%7CBLN-22726_buyer_banner%3DB%7Cignite_web_better_session%3DC%7CEBAYKAD-3536_floor_ai%3DA%7Cignite_improve_session%3DC%7CBLN-24684-enc-brndg-data%3DA%7Cliberty_group%3DY%7CFLPRO-130-churn-reason%3DB%7CEKMO-100_reorder_postad%3DB%7CKLUE-274-financing%3DB%7Clws-aws-traffic%3DB%7CBLN-25450_Initial_message%3DB%7CBLN-24652_category_alert%3DB%7CBLN-21783_testingtime%3DB%7Caudex-awr-update%3DA%7CEBAYKAD-2252_group-assign%3DH%7CBLN-25216-new-user-badges%3DB%7CBLN-25556_INIT_MSG_V2%3DB%7CDESKTOP-promo-switch%3DA%7Caudex-libertyjs-reporting%3DA%7CPLC-189_plc-migration%3DB%7Caudex-libertyjs-update%3DA%7Cperformance-test-desktop%3DC%7CBIPHONE-9700_buy_now%3DB%7CEKMO-243_MyAdsC2b_ABC%3DA%7Cprebid-update%3DA%7CEKTNM-4424_DSA_AD_FLAG%3DA%7Cpubads-behind-consent%3DA%7CPLC-104_plc-login%3DB%7Cdesktop_payment_badge_SRP%3DR%22%2C%22ls%22%3A%22k%3Diphone%252013%22%7D',
    'uh': '%7B%22sh%22%3A%22k%3Diphone%252013%22%7D',
    'bm_sv': '0E46F6D4C2D15DDF4037D3219522F169~YAAQjGZWuLYmhJGPAQAAc7HtnBfptI0O/cZh+z71bjX7FWoEWfWi+7rSmJtAdtnHr2Yy6Sml0PivsexsxpEKRqSMQ6ykXGA2uoSw845qdTHuHFptR+QNvMHbvH/VH/cLCl5ACpcudk630IFOv5PevfMyfExV481WLWdi/qiNeZTnGPaMNkfNGtb6nRhJan8bo9pPBMP4ZvblfI33UGrSX3mmVIEuQ2CZ9w2o6QF97BCNHkRLzeHAyzVnysmuxchKgTS4GHCq~1',
    'bm_sz': 'DC20044AB93A95DA69EEDF3CBC61933F~YAAQjGZWuLcmhJGPAQAAc7HtnBfghyhORTugDA+HeFjnh5DSij+T1QpBc1T3YOBc7JF2Kd/LUNEwSqqPtyRQMQqA6S5UoqG2w3rLfYD4LfF3p4Oe35m8blAYcoozf4uBqfBuD4kPWSAEdCCW4Qz3yPBOFwLGDO3Imik7kxYRH+0PpEGheEoo6JQSXKpdHrGRhLXOJecz1EKW/uRKZf2n35KDL7Q5uNdu4ZMkwKG4Tsv2b1lNYr5AsR+OyvPuTnHyGbyIo3IsqmoeL4ZDBvgdGlrbhcAyJdm6D8HFNyaNgCIPLyiH/nbL1Md2mVu99LlQHI/atUHs2Xls/fNrHeiEM14d1gRlmS+0t5wt2eB+C3k4KUgjrpSta8jR7hvBMHq+JWrZ71tUnLjVXgozyprHuWzgQYHSN8DQE9lVEBtuqbkyO0eQZmUPJoUBf/p7raJ7rGiX+R6P~3225913~3749176',
    '_pbjs_userid_consent_data': '1948453571612999',
    '_sharedid': '2cc48544-17d6-40f0-8055-433f3bd0eebb',
    'ttd_TDID': '5af2038d-4201-4381-a705-008be357e42b',
    '_abck': '0BE7DECF6A441CAED9FAE60DD4A2D439~-1~YAAQjGZWuGYnhJGPAQAAF7ntnAvIJaPDK0JcFilje/7MpZxzpI0e91nvMkptlAnNzcvbc/7RsC1cJb9t+U/5WcPd8vR5hPtB4B5DzzMkYqetbfONwbgM9rxJ7WzQZDmNXvHso6HgE1CoHrazlFHCdapmnPYQZf9rKTSLi3bpmBLXajRz9jguHHl/OSeKz60PNLlcnQKxgUbDiS2dOz9K/fdl5pYP8fD54/2/h6P9mGBtoAeUAxPNRUZNuqgo3KhfSpryre97I0qQjtZIffvnvrTTh+VGLk+XXGxxWA3+KQZ7fk89MhFNR6X6iPIln2KisoLu/M7FUsmhBUHuGW4GYxSuzePypKxJLosRLHD2VngeRjrSbP5dEuFI0ib3ZbVGoOm0EdrBwwg4gtTbfH82~-1~-1~-1',
    'ioam2018': '001004bb35748f346664cf549:1742244769311:1716324769311:.kleinanzeigen.de:3:ebaykanz:ebayK-2:noevent:1716324775481:xwyv7z',
    '__gsas': 'ID=06678aa415f2bae1:T=1716324775:RT=1716324775:S=ALNI_MY8M9AWvnu9c04kmWUotsmzbZE9Kw',
    '_uetsid': '24053ee0178711ef995c73a37e750a44',
    '_uetvid': '2815b710edc911edb77b397abfb0ec6b',
    '_ga': 'GA1.1.496654825.1716324769',
    '__gads': 'ID=913a6a8a4ed5f68f:T=1716324775:RT=1716324775:S=ALNI_MbcqPiXeD1up-CfoDLjbZWHR3i2qQ',
    '__gpi': 'UID=00000e283afa9424:T=1716324775:RT=1716324775:S=ALNI_MaKh8LN1b8hyjtkjGF1q_PBkaguBQ',
    '__eoi': 'ID=30ca85bff1e0487a:T=1716324775:RT=1716324775:S=AA-AfjZA4xIy4PLoxMR9l_uqa7AS',
    '_ga_123456': 'GS1.1.1716324776.1.0.1716324776.0.0.1971217686',
    '_clsk': 'kf2mvr%7C1716324777066%7C2%7C0%7Cv.clarity.ms%2Fcollect',
    '_ga_6V6MWRHVN8': 'GS1.1.1716324769.1.1.1716324777.0.0.804489043',
    'axd': '4362638687387987014',
    'tis': '',
}

headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,ru-DE;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.5',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    # 'cookie': '_clck=or3005%7C2%7Cfly%7C0%7C1602; CSRF-TOKEN=14dc299d-30f2-4d98-9ff4-c4fbe8f3e569; ak_bmsc=C1C8A8F7FF391E9820102E8CA4EBB694~000000000000000000000000000000~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; ekConsentBucketTcf2=full2-exp; ekConsentTcf2={%22customVersion%22:6%2C%22encodedConsentString%22:%22CP-9ugAP-9ugAE1ACADEAzEgAP_gAAAAAAYgJepV5D7dbWFFcX53aPt0OY0X19DzIsQhBhSBAyAFgBOQ8JQA02EyNASgBiACEAAAoxZBAAFEHABEAQCAQAAEAADsIgQEgAAIIABEgBEQAAJYAAoKAAAgEAAIgAIFEgAAmBjQKdLmXUiAhIAACgAQACABAICAAgMAAAAIAAIAAAAAAgAAgABgIAIAAAAAARAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAACi0AGAAIJelIAMAAQS9JQAYAAgl6QgAwABBL0dABgACCXoyADAAEEvRUAGAAIJeiIAMAAQS9DQAYAAgl6EgAwABBL0A.YAAAAAAAA60A%22%2C%22googleConsentGiven%22:true%2C%22consentInterpretation%22:{%22googleAdvertisingFeaturesAllowed%22:true%2C%22googleAnalyticsAllowed%22:true%2C%22infonlineAllowed%22:true%2C%22theAdexAllowed%22:true%2C%22criteoAllowed%22:true%2C%22facebookAllowed%22:true%2C%22amazonAdvertisingAllowed%22:true%2C%22rtbHouseAllowed%22:true%2C%22linkedInAllowed%22:true%2C%22theTradeDeskAllowed%22:true%2C%22microsoftAdvertisingAllowed%22:true%2C%22pianoAllowed%22:true%2C%22renaultAllowed%22:false}}; iom_consent=0107ff0000&1716324769286; _gid=GA1.2.1532272070.1716324769; __rtbh.uid=%7B%22eventType%22%3A%22uid%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22unknown%22%7D; clientId=496654825.1716324769; _gat=1; FPID=FPID2.2.AOuBPGhHzWT6LnAkpY5kTJhKrpSS%2FkCqyy4lC0XgstU%3D.1716324769; FPLC=q%2BEjZGxjkPyzi60Jabi2fnha46CbqeBJ6r5U2WbreeneTYQSQm2wogu4TCxyjhFwIpCvNTT5dL%2FIMuVk77ixOiL%2Btpwkr%2BhfOXvIFfaYo8901edWtL0mN0jGi%2FQbew%3D%3D; FPAU=1.2.1242298381.1716324771; FPGSID=1.1716324770.1716324770.G-6V6MWRHVN8.TCed7UzLYaViqx_51MOpqg; up=%7B%22ln%22%3A%22294028564%22%2C%22lln%22%3A%229813e7ea-faff-435e-a600-244146dd8da9%22%2C%22llstv%22%3A%22BLN-25381-ka-offboarding%3DB%7CBLN-23401_buyNow_in_chat%3DB%7CBLN-18532_highlight%3DA%7CBLN-23248_BuyNow_SB%3DB%7CBLN-22726_buyer_banner%3DB%7Cignite_web_better_session%3DC%7CEBAYKAD-3536_floor_ai%3DA%7Cignite_improve_session%3DC%7CBLN-24684-enc-brndg-data%3DA%7Cliberty_group%3DY%7CFLPRO-130-churn-reason%3DB%7CEKMO-100_reorder_postad%3DB%7CKLUE-274-financing%3DB%7Clws-aws-traffic%3DB%7CBLN-25450_Initial_message%3DB%7CBLN-24652_category_alert%3DB%7CBLN-21783_testingtime%3DB%7Caudex-awr-update%3DA%7CEBAYKAD-2252_group-assign%3DH%7CBLN-25216-new-user-badges%3DB%7CBLN-25556_INIT_MSG_V2%3DB%7CDESKTOP-promo-switch%3DA%7Caudex-libertyjs-reporting%3DA%7CPLC-189_plc-migration%3DB%7Caudex-libertyjs-update%3DA%7Cperformance-test-desktop%3DC%7CBIPHONE-9700_buy_now%3DB%7CEKMO-243_MyAdsC2b_ABC%3DA%7Cprebid-update%3DA%7CEKTNM-4424_DSA_AD_FLAG%3DA%7Cpubads-behind-consent%3DA%7CPLC-104_plc-login%3DB%7Cdesktop_payment_badge_SRP%3DR%22%2C%22ls%22%3A%22k%3Diphone%252013%22%7D; uh=%7B%22sh%22%3A%22k%3Diphone%252013%22%7D; bm_sv=0E46F6D4C2D15DDF4037D3219522F169~YAAQjGZWuLYmhJGPAQAAc7HtnBfptI0O/cZh+z71bjX7FWoEWfWi+7rSmJtAdtnHr2Yy6Sml0PivsexsxpEKRqSMQ6ykXGA2uoSw845qdTHuHFptR+QNvMHbvH/VH/cLCl5ACpcudk630IFOv5PevfMyfExV481WLWdi/qiNeZTnGPaMNkfNGtb6nRhJan8bo9pPBMP4ZvblfI33UGrSX3mmVIEuQ2CZ9w2o6QF97BCNHkRLzeHAyzVnysmuxchKgTS4GHCq~1; bm_sz=DC20044AB93A95DA69EEDF3CBC61933F~YAAQjGZWuLcmhJGPAQAAc7HtnBfghyhORTugDA+HeFjnh5DSij+T1QpBc1T3YOBc7JF2Kd/LUNEwSqqPtyRQMQqA6S5UoqG2w3rLfYD4LfF3p4Oe35m8blAYcoozf4uBqfBuD4kPWSAEdCCW4Qz3yPBOFwLGDO3Imik7kxYRH+0PpEGheEoo6JQSXKpdHrGRhLXOJecz1EKW/uRKZf2n35KDL7Q5uNdu4ZMkwKG4Tsv2b1lNYr5AsR+OyvPuTnHyGbyIo3IsqmoeL4ZDBvgdGlrbhcAyJdm6D8HFNyaNgCIPLyiH/nbL1Md2mVu99LlQHI/atUHs2Xls/fNrHeiEM14d1gRlmS+0t5wt2eB+C3k4KUgjrpSta8jR7hvBMHq+JWrZ71tUnLjVXgozyprHuWzgQYHSN8DQE9lVEBtuqbkyO0eQZmUPJoUBf/p7raJ7rGiX+R6P~3225913~3749176; _pbjs_userid_consent_data=1948453571612999; _sharedid=2cc48544-17d6-40f0-8055-433f3bd0eebb; ttd_TDID=5af2038d-4201-4381-a705-008be357e42b; _abck=0BE7DECF6A441CAED9FAE60DD4A2D439~-1~YAAQjGZWuGYnhJGPAQAAF7ntnAvIJaPDK0JcFilje/7MpZxzpI0e91nvMkptlAnNzcvbc/7RsC1cJb9t+U/5WcPd8vR5hPtB4B5DzzMkYqetbfONwbgM9rxJ7WzQZDmNXvHso6HgE1CoHrazlFHCdapmnPYQZf9rKTSLi3bpmBLXajRz9jguHHl/OSeKz60PNLlcnQKxgUbDiS2dOz9K/fdl5pYP8fD54/2/h6P9mGBtoAeUAxPNRUZNuqgo3KhfSpryre97I0qQjtZIffvnvrTTh+VGLk+XXGxxWA3+KQZ7fk89MhFNR6X6iPIln2KisoLu/M7FUsmhBUHuGW4GYxSuzePypKxJLosRLHD2VngeRjrSbP5dEuFI0ib3ZbVGoOm0EdrBwwg4gtTbfH82~-1~-1~-1; ioam2018=001004bb35748f346664cf549:1742244769311:1716324769311:.kleinanzeigen.de:3:ebaykanz:ebayK-2:noevent:1716324775481:xwyv7z; __gsas=ID=06678aa415f2bae1:T=1716324775:RT=1716324775:S=ALNI_MY8M9AWvnu9c04kmWUotsmzbZE9Kw; _uetsid=24053ee0178711ef995c73a37e750a44; _uetvid=2815b710edc911edb77b397abfb0ec6b; _ga=GA1.1.496654825.1716324769; __gads=ID=913a6a8a4ed5f68f:T=1716324775:RT=1716324775:S=ALNI_MbcqPiXeD1up-CfoDLjbZWHR3i2qQ; __gpi=UID=00000e283afa9424:T=1716324775:RT=1716324775:S=ALNI_MaKh8LN1b8hyjtkjGF1q_PBkaguBQ; __eoi=ID=30ca85bff1e0487a:T=1716324775:RT=1716324775:S=AA-AfjZA4xIy4PLoxMR9l_uqa7AS; _ga_123456=GS1.1.1716324776.1.0.1716324776.0.0.1971217686; _clsk=kf2mvr%7C1716324777066%7C2%7C0%7Cv.clarity.ms%2Fcollect; _ga_6V6MWRHVN8=GS1.1.1716324769.1.1.1716324777.0.0.804489043; axd=4362638687387987014; tis=',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'priority': 'u=0, i',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="125", "Chromium";v="125", "Not.A/Brand";v="24"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.kleinanzeigen.de/s-iphone-13/k0', cookies=cookies, headers=headers)

With the python request I get the response that the IP address is banned. How is this possible? With curl it does work multiple times even after executing the python code.
requests                          2.31.0
requests-file                     1.5.1
requests-toolbelt                 1.0.0
urllib3                           2.2.1
Python 3.11.7


I tried your python code and got essentially the same results in both cases.

Given that user Barmar has no trouble with your code, it's possible that curl is somehow getting the content from some cache (like a proxy, or something else on your system or network) while your Python code does not. It seems like the service you are trying to reach may have blocked your IP due to bad requests, or too many requests, while our IPs have not (yet) been banned for the same reason. You could consider running the code using another network connection to test.

My IP is not banned when I try to use a browser I am getting the response. Curiously I tried to run it from docker container as a python script and there is works fine. Thats okay for me but I dont understand it
